# Installing Eclipse Market on Android Bundle

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins

I'm using Eclipse ADT Bundle from Google http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html And there is no Eclipse Market preinstalled. So I downloaded it via Help - > Install new software. 
Eclipse Market installed correctly but everytime I do anything with it, it returns error :

```
    Unexpected exception: org/eclipse/equinox/internal/p2/repository/RepositoryTransport
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

What's wrong?

Comment: This might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020719/what-could-cause-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception

Comment: thanks, but this is Eclipse software problem, not my code. They say on the internet that this might be server problem though.

Comment: Instead, try finding the real cause of the problem with `catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e(TAG,Log.getStackTraceString(e)); 
}`. See if this outputs something.