# Eclipse application package renaming tool give an error

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying rename my application package using **eclipse Android Tools**. It is working in other projects but unfortunately not in my project. :(.

It gives me Internal error "**java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**". Please find end of thread for full error.

In project,
I have several library projects inculcated (like SlidingMenu, ABS, PullToRefresh, google-play-services_lib). Also have jars like gson, Jakson, twitter 4J and other.
Also i have around 35 packages for different modules.

I don't know what causes this problem. I have tried many things but haven't got any solution yet.

Please help me. Thanks in advance. :)

Here is full detailed Error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$13.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1679)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1676)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.createChange(RefactoringWizard.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.computeUserInputSuccessorPage(RefactoringWizard.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.getStartingPage(RefactoringWizard.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showStartingPage(WizardDialog.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation$1.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:122)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.RenamePackageAction.initiateAndroidPackageRefactoring(RenamePackageAction.java:168)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.RenamePackageAction.promptNewName(RenamePackageAction.java:151)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.RenamePackageAction.run(RenamePackageAction.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.updateJavaFileImports(ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.java:149)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring$JavaFileVisitor.visit(ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource$2.visit(Resource.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource$1.visitElement(Resource.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.iterate(ElementTreeIterator.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:108)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.createChange(ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CreateChangeOperation.run(CreateChangeOperation.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Comment: Don't know where the actual error comes from, but it seems to be related to opening the progress window.

Comment: @Pietu1998 yes but it is working fine in my other projects.

Comment: Took another look and the error is actually occurring while Eclipse is updating `import`s in your Java files.

Comment: Thanks @Pietu1998 for reply. So any idea what should i do over here?

Comment: Well, you could change the `import`s yourself, it's a lot of work but if the tool doesn't work I have no idea how to do it. Maybe you could still try renaming the package yourself (via normal refactoring), but then check "update fully qualified names in non-Java text files" in the rename window.

Comment: did u try cleaning the application??

Comment: Yes. I have tried many things. Cleaning of an application even created new workspace but not working there also.

Comment: i also had same error while doing manually. Please use notepad++ to rename you package name. in Notepad++ Search->Find in Files.
I think these error are coming cause somehwere your package name didn't got changed.

Comment: Would you like to take a look onto this link might be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020719/what-could-cause-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem seems to be have multiple problem but it shows one kind of error.

Please check for the unused code in your application i.e unused inner class, unused public class if you found that, remove that and try to clean the project and rename it.

If there are errors in the XML files then also this kind of problems may happen. you need to check on that too.

All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether any of your class is fully commented or not.If yes, uncomment it.

Also, check this : [rename package error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680717/rename-package-name-inside-android-project/19681399#19681399)

Answer (score -1):

if you try  to rename application package you should update all references in your application. Have you also updates package name in android manifest file.

Comment: Yes i know. But i have so many references and also so many custom views in xmls. So i am using eclipse tool Android Tools > rename application package it gives me above error.