# Rename package name inside Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm not able to rename package name inside Android project. I'm using Android tools/Rename Application Package. I'm using ndroid ADeveloper Tools

Build: v22.2.1-833290

Here is error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$13.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1679)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1676)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.createChange(RefactoringWizard.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.computeUserInputSuccessorPage(RefactoringWizard.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.getStartingPage(RefactoringWizard.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showStartingPage(WizardDialog.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation$1.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:122)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.RenamePackageAction.initiateAndroidPackageRefactoring(RenamePackageAction.java:168)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.RenamePackageAction.promptNewName(RenamePackageAction.java:151)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.RenamePackageAction.run(RenamePackageAction.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    ............
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.iterate(ElementTreeIterator.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:108)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.createChange(ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CreateChangeOperation.run(CreateChangeOperation.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Any help? thank you

Comment: Check whether any of your class is fully commented or not.If yes, uncomment it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether any of your class is fully commented or not.If yes, uncomment it.

Comment: Also, check for empty classes.

Answer (score 0):

change package name in manifest

```
    package="com.example.appname"
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on package folder select Refector select rename.....cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any empty classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to using the Project -> Android Tools -> Rename Application Package

In the example we'll rename com.my.app to com.my.newapp

**ALWAYS BACKUP PROJECTS BEFORE REFACTORING**

1. Expand your project -> gen
2. Right click com.my.app and select Refactor, enter new name com.my.newapp
3. The files will be renamed and updated. A package matching the old name will be created, ignore it for now
4. Open your AndroidManifest.xml and change the Package name to com.my.newapp
5. Remove the old com.my.app package from gen
6. Expand Project -> src
7. Right click com.my.app and refactor to com.my.newapp (include subclasses but don't do text)

Your project should now build with it's new package name. You can now update any textual references to com.my.newapp, check the full AndroidManifest.xml for any extra things to update.

Comment: I used this method to rename a project after the standard mechanism failed. It worked in the end, though I needed to manually correct some silly errors that eclipse made in changing the package name + change the references in the AndroidManifest. The errors were pretty easy to find using the "Problems" list in Eclipse.