# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when trying to run Play Application

Tags: java, linux, scala, playframework

I am currently trying to set up a scala + play framework development environment.
I am working on a Ubuntu LTS 12.04, with Open JDK and Java Versions:

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_25

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

I installed the most up to date Play and Scala Versions

```
$ play
play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_25), http://www.playframework.com

$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.10.3 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

$ scalac -version
Scala compiler version 2.10.3 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

When run a scala test application with play I get the following exception:

```
$ run
[info] Updating {file:/home/cornelius/hello/}hello...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at scala.compat.Platform$.<init>(Platform.scala:112)
at scala.compat.Platform$.<clinit>(Platform.scala)
.
.
.
.
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 02.12.2013 17:32:43
```

Can anyone help me out on this?

EDIT 1: Here comes the full stack trace including the caused by section. Inspecting http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/linux.html and https://askubuntu.com/questions/148171/dropbox-error-echo-100000-sudo-tee-proc-sys-fs-inotify-max-user-watches helped me to solve the issue!

```
Caused by: net.contentobjects.jnotify.linux.JNotifyException_linux: Error watching /home/cornelius/hello/app : No space left on device
.
.
.
.
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Try printing the cause of the InvocationTargetException to see what the real problem was. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020719/what-could-cause-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception

Comment: FYI, the scala compiler version actually used is not the one in your `$PATH`, it will be the Play default (unless you set `scalaVersion` explicitly in `build.sbt`). Do `scala-version` at the play prompt to see what it is.

Comment: I have had this same problem. If I control-D and re run it will work. This is only a temporary fix as it will stop working a few requests later.