# understanding Invocation Target Exception wrapping in Java

Tags: java, system.reflection, invocationtargetexception

m is a method and I want to invoke it on a specific Instance through reflection.
the following code show how I did the invokation:

```
try {
    m.invoke(classInstance);                
} catch (OOPAssertionError e) {

} catch (Exception e) {
    system.out(e.getCause().getClass().getName());
}
```

Now the Instance suppose to throw the following class when I invoke the specific method I just tried to invoke earlier, which is m in the previous code:

```
public class OOPAssertionError extends AssertionError {
}
```

I thought that the program will catch OOPAssertionError but actually it catch Exception instead .
and prints the following line : "package.OOPAssertionError".

why is that happening ?

Comment: Have you read the Javadoc of `Method#invoke`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InvocationTargetException` wraps your method's exceptions, like was written in javadoc.

See [What could cause java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020719/what-could-cause-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception) for more details.

Good luck in reflections! ;)