# Android intent activity in external lib

Tags: android, android-intent, dex, dynamic-library

1. I want to startActivity the class in the external AndroidLibrary..

   ```
   **Error :** Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.fsd.ddc/com.fsd.toastlib.ToastActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.fsd.toastlib.ToastActivity"
   ```

   I have already register the activity name in the manifest file

   (Main) **com.fsd.ddc.AndroidManifest.xml**

   ```
   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

       <activity android:name="com.fsd.toastlib.ToastActivity">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.fsd.toastlib.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>

       <activity android:name=".DDCActivity">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity android:name=".TestActivity"></activity>
   </application>
   ```

   (Main) **com.fsd.ddc.DDCActivity.java**

   ```
   public class DDCActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   // Buffer size for file copying.  While 8kb is used in this sample, you
   // may want to tweak it based on actual size of the secondary dex file involved.
   private static final int BUF_SIZE = 8 * 1024;
   private static final String SECONDARY_DEX_NAME = "com.fsd.toastlib.jar";

   private Button mToastButton = null;
   private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = null;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_ddc);

       Button btn_class = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_class);

       // Before the secondary dex file can be processed by the DexClassLoader,
       // it has to be first copied from asset resource to a storage location.
       final File dexInternalStoragePath = new File(getDir("dex", Context.MODE_PRIVATE),
               SECONDARY_DEX_NAME);

       if (!dexInternalStoragePath.exists()) {
           mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
                   getResources().getString(R.string.diag_title),
                   getResources().getString(R.string.diag_message), true, false);
           // Perform the file copying in an AsyncTask.
           (new PrepareDexTask()).execute(dexInternalStoragePath);
       } else {
           btn_class.setEnabled(true);
       }

       btn_class.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               final File optimizedDexOutputPath = getDir("outdex", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

               // Initialize the class loader with the secondary dex file.
               DexClassLoader cl = new DexClassLoader(dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath(),
                       optimizedDexOutputPath.getAbsolutePath(),
                       null,
                       getClassLoader());

               Class<Object> libProviderClazz = null;

               try {
                   libProviderClazz = (Class<Object>) cl.loadClass("com.fsd.toastlib.ToastActivity");

                   // CHANGED: THIS STARTS PROPERLY YOUR ACTIVITY ONCE THE CLASS LOADED
                   final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), libProviderClazz);
                   startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
               } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                   // handle that Exception properly here
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       });
   }

   // File I/O code to copy the secondary dex file from asset resource to internal storage.
   private boolean prepareDex(File dexInternalStoragePath) {
       BufferedInputStream bis = null;
       OutputStream dexWriter = null;

       try {
           //bis = new BufferedInputStream(getAssets().open(SECONDARY_DEX_NAME));
           Log.i("customClassLoader", "test");
           File extDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
           Log.i("customClassLoader", extDir.getAbsolutePath());
           File dexExternalStorage = new File(extDir, SECONDARY_DEX_NAME);
           Log.i("customClassLoader", dexExternalStorage.getAbsolutePath());
           bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(dexExternalStorage));
           dexWriter = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dexInternalStoragePath));
           byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
           int len;
           while((len = bis.read(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
               dexWriter.write(buf, 0, len);
           }
           dexWriter.close();
           bis.close();
           return true;
       } catch (IOException e) {
           if (dexWriter != null) {
               try {
                   dexWriter.close();
               } catch (IOException ioe) {
                   ioe.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
           if (bis != null) {
               try {
                   bis.close();
               } catch (IOException ioe) {
                   ioe.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
           return false;
       }
   }

   private class PrepareDexTask extends AsyncTask<File, Void, Boolean> {

       @Override
       protected void onCancelled() {
           super.onCancelled();
           if (mProgressDialog != null) mProgressDialog.cancel();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
           if (mProgressDialog != null) mProgressDialog.cancel();
       }

       @Override
       protected Boolean doInBackground(File... dexInternalStoragePaths) {
           prepareDex(dexInternalStoragePaths[0]);
           return null;
       }
   }
   }
   ```

   (Library) **com.fsd.toastlib.ToastActivity.java**

   ```
   public class ToastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_toast);

       Button main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_main);

       main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               TextView teks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lib_text);
               teks.setText("Start");

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Game is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       });
   }
   }
   ```
2. How to generate jar that include the res folder, currently it only contains the java file. Then, can I access it directly like my code in ToastActivity.java, ex:

   TextView teks = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.lib_text);

Code that I used to generate jar file

(Library) **build.gradle**

```html
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

// Define some tasks which are used in the build process
task copyClasses(type: Copy) { // Copy the assembled *.class files for only the current namespace into a new directory
    // get directory for current namespace (PLUGIN_NAMESPACE = 'com.example.toastlib')
    String PLUGIN_NAMESPACE = "com.fsd.toastlib"
    def namespacePath = PLUGIN_NAMESPACE.replaceAll("\\.","/")
    // set source and destination directories
    from "build/intermediates/classes/release/${namespacePath}/"
    into "build/intermediates/dex/${namespacePath}/"

    // exclude classes which don't have a corresponding .java entry in the source directory
    def remExt = { name -> name.lastIndexOf('.').with {it != -1 ? name[0..<it] : name} }
    eachFile {details ->
        def thisFile = new File("${projectDir}/src/main/java/${namespacePath}/", remExt(details.name)+".java")
        if (!(thisFile.exists())) {
            details.exclude()
        }
    }
}

task assembleExternalJar << {
    // Get the location of the Android SDK
    ext.androidSdkDir = System.env.ANDROID_HOME
    if(androidSdkDir == null) {
        Properties localProps = new Properties()
        localProps.load(new FileInputStream(file('local.properties')))
        ext.androidSdkDir = localProps['sdk.dir']
    }
    // Make sure no existing jar file exists as this will cause dx to fail
    new File("${buildDir}/intermediates/dex/com.fsd.toastlib.jar").delete();
    // Use command line dx utility to convert *.class files into classes.dex inside jar archive
    String cmdExt = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? '.bat' : ''
    exec {
        commandLine "${androidSdkDir}\\build-tools\\26.0.1\\dx${cmdExt}", '--dex',
                "--output=${buildDir}/intermediates/dex/com.fsd.toastlib.jar",
                "${buildDir}/intermediates/dex/"
    }
    copyJarToOutputs.execute()
}

task copyJarToOutputs(type: Copy) {
    // Copy the built jar archive to the outputs folder
    from 'build/intermediates/dex/'
    into 'build/outputs/'
    include '*.jar'
}

// Set the dependencies of the build tasks so that assembleExternalJar does a complete build
copyClasses.dependsOn(assemble)
assembleExternalJar.dependsOn(copyClasses)
```

Comment: Are you making an AAR?

Comment: no, I make standard Android Library, should I make an AAR for the best practice?

Comment: I was just curious how the other code is packaged and how you've put it on your apps classpath

Comment: I have added the build.gradle code, please take a look

Comment: Okay, why do you need a JAR file? You can directly compile this library into the other app

Comment: I don want it compiled in my main app.
it should be compiled when the user download it like expansion file.
(I wanna make mini-game inside a game, so when the player click it, the jar file will be downloaded and executed)

Comment: I have read the AAR library implementaion, the library must be inside the main apk

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how you're loading the library as a JAR file.

Comment: the jar file works fine, Actually I have another function in the class, it show a toast and its working. I used dexClassLoader

But intent does not work, my referrence:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212623/interacting-with-dynamically-loaded-library-using-dexclassloader