# Android Error inflating class com.shamanland.fonticon.FontIconView

Tags: android

I am using Shamanland FontIconView but my Activity can't be started and my app crashes

***Steack Trace:***

```
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.mmido.asfarandroid, PID: 14010
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mmido.asfarandroid/com.example.mmido.asfarandroid.As
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2385)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.shamanland.fonticon.FontIconView
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at com.example.mmido.asfarandroid.AsfarApp.PaymentActivity.onCreate(PaymentActivity.java:13)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
       at com.example.mmido.asfarandroid.AsfarApp.PaymentActivity.onCreate(PaymentActivity.java:13) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
       at com.shamanland.fonticon.FontIconTypefaceHolder.getTypeface(FontIconTypefaceHolder.java:11)
       at com.shamanland.fonticon.FontIconView.<init>(FontIconView.java:129)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
       at com.example.mmido.asfarandroid.AsfarApp.PaymentActivity.onCreate(PaymentActivity.java:13) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

***My Layout:***

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/pf_tittle_header_height"
        android:background="@color/pf_gray">

        <com.shamanland.fonticon.FontIconView
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/pf_border_space"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onBackPressed"
            android:text="@string/icon_left_circled"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/pf_back_icon_txt_size"
            app:pressedGlowColor="@color/pf_green"
            app:pressedGlowRadius="@dimen/pf_icon_glow_radius" />
```

*Line #15* is this line `<com.shamanland.fonticon.FontIconView`
i checked String values and dimension used in FontIconView and they are correct .what is the error here please?

***Thanks.***

Comment: Is there another "caused by" caluse down the log? The reason I'm asking is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020719/what-could-cause-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception

Comment: are you use this third party class?

Comment: @Vaiden i updated the log with "all Caused by" clauses

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper yes i do i added it in dependencies in gradle file

Comment: The last time I had an inflater issue like this was when I forgot to put a line in build.gradle dependency. Can you inspect the apk and check if you have FontIconView there?

Comment: @Fabio when i stop on `fonticon.FontIconView` and click go to declaration it takes me to `FontIconView` class already

Comment: @Asmaa the illegal state exception is most likely to be the cause. If you still want to check for the class inside the apk, rename the apk to .zip, open with WinZip or similar and see if you can find the corresponding .class file there.

Comment: @Fabio i renamed the App apk and it can't be opened as ziped file

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same problem day before yesterday in my project, so the solution I found is: Just paste your .ttf file inside the asset folder in your project (if folder is not there just create one inside app->src->main) and initialize the `FontIconTypefaceHolder()` in your main activity inside `onCreate()` method. Like as

```
FontIconTypefaceHolder.init(getAssets(),"icon.ttf");
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor throws an IllegalStateException due to:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
       at com.shamanland.fonticon.FontIconTypefaceHolder.getTypeface(FontIconTypefaceHolder.java:11)
```

Since this project is [open source](https://github.com/shamanland/fonticon), put a breakpoint there and debug the issue.

Comment: i will try that now

Comment: i added this library in dependencies in gradle file i don't know where should i put a breakpoint?

Comment: Write FontIconTypefaceHolder icon; anywhere, alt+ left click the class name will take you to the source code. Then create a breakpoint there.

Comment: i did that now and this is the line that cause the exception 
`setTypeface(FontIconTypefaceHolder.getTypeface());`

Comment: `public static Typeface getTypeface() {
        if (sTypeface == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        return sTypeface;
    }` sTypeface  is null so it throws exception  .. why is that ??

Comment: @AsmaaRashad a wild guess here - this is an attribute that the library expects in the XML. Look at where sTypeface is assigned for the exact attribute name.

Comment: @AsmaaRashad Did you solve this problem? I am facing the same.