# Firebase RecyclerAdapter InvocationTargetException issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have been trying for last 4 hours to narrow down the view holder issue but cant seem to find it. I've been following and copying this code. 
[Friendly Chat - Android](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/tree/master/android)

But still no hope. I've been getting

**"java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:167)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:549)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5891)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCrea
```

**View Holder**

```
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView messageTextView;
    public TextView messengerTextView;
    public CircleImageView messengerImageView;

    public MessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        messageTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        messengerTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messengerTextView);
        messengerImageView = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messengerImageView);
    }
   .....
}
```

**Creating adapter**

```
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessageViewHolder>(
            Message.class,
            R.layout.item_message,
            MessageViewHolder.class,
            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD)) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder viewHolder, Message friendlyMessage, int position) {
            viewHolder.messageTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getText());
            viewHolder.messengerTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getName());
            if (friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl() == null) {
                viewHolder.messengerImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MessageActivity.this,
                        R.drawable.profilepic_placeholder));
            } else {
                Glide.with(MessageActivity.this)
                        .load(friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl())
                        .into(viewHolder.messengerImageView);
            }
        }
    };
```

**Setting Adapter**

```
 mMessageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
 mMessageRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
```

Once I start the activity, within few seconds app crashes :( and throws that InvocationTargetException

**Edit**
Libraries that I am using

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.5.3'
```

Comment: The same call stack appears in this [FirebaseUI issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/94).  Maybe you'll understand the resolution there.  I don't.  Also, the [setup instructions for FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) indicate you should be using UI version 0.4.4 or 0.5.3 with Database version 9.4.0

Comment: @qbix - Yes, I already read that issue in github. I tried changing my view holder to static/non-static, public/private, even tried making view holder to a separate stand alone class, still failing :( also updated ui libraries

Comment: [This is the line that's raising the exception](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/0.5.3/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java#L167): `LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType, parent, false)`, so it looks like it's unable to inflate your layout from the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after so much trial, it's just one piece of word that fixed it. It's 'final' keyword on my populateViewholder. Even thou my view holder is not final but still that final keyword made it work. Not sure why and how. Didn't know firebase recyclerviewadapter would be that strict

**Adapter**

```
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessageViewHolder>(
            Message.class,
            R.layout.item_message,
            MessageViewHolder.class,
            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD)) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder, Message friendlyMessage, int position) {
            viewHolder.messageTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getText());
            viewHolder.messengerTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getName());
            if (friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl() == null) {
                viewHolder.messengerImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MessageActivity.this,
                        R.drawable.profilepic_placeholder));
            } else {
                Glide.with(MessageActivity.this)
                        .load(friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl())
                        .into(viewHolder.messengerImageView);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you get wrong  private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter mFirebaseAdapter; Double check your Values or RecyclerView, because arguments are invalid. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6020758/6821007

Edit: compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2' and Make support some widget like RecyclerView