# JSON error using Struts2

Tags: json, struts2

When I start my jsp I use a javascript function to charge in session a user. The javascript function use JSON with a struts2 action. This is the code:

JSP:

```
<body>
   <script>usarAJAXCargarCookie();</script>
   ...
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function usarAJAXCargarCookie() {
   var userCookie = getCookie('userCookieSL');
   $.getJSON('ajaxCookie', {
      userCookie: userCookie
   }, function (jsonResponse) {
   });
}
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="ajaxCookie" class="Acciones.HomeFavoritos" method="ajaxCookie">
   <result type="json">
      <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
      <param name="noCache">true</param>
   </result>
</action>
```

HomeFavoritos.java

```
@SkipValidation
public String ajaxCookie() throws Exception{        
    if(sesion==null){
        sesion=ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
    }
    if(sesion.get("usuarioLogueado") == null || sesion.get("usuarioLogueado").equals("")){
        cargarUsuarioNoLogueado(sesion, userCookie);
    } else {
        cargarUsuarioLogueado(sesion);
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

And I receive this error:

```
Grave:   Exception occurred during processing request: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:102)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:116)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.createJSONString(JSONResult.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
```

Comment: This is unclear what are you trying to return as json response.

Answer (score 0):

[InvocationTargetException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6020758/1654265) is just a wrap around the real exception, that you're not showing us.

It will probably be a serialization exception, so consider using a [`root` object as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17149414/1654265), instead of serializing the whole action.

Also try using english names in the code, and please, NEVER write package names with something different from lowercase (**A**cciones.HomeFavoritos...)