# Test with Coverage Intellij Error

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I can run all test and they passed but when i run with coverage i got error

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent 
failedjava.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at 
com.intellij.rt.coverage.main.CoveragePremain.
premain(CoveragePremain.java:66)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
at
```

com.intellij.rt.coverage.instrumentation.Instrumentator.premain(Instrumentator.j
    ava:65)
    ... 11 more

```
Process finished with exit code 1
Exception in thread "main"
```

Why without coverage option they passed but with coverage not? And how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was casued by non-ASCII characters in Intellij path. The solution is to change directory in Intellij properties:

> Workaround:
>   Add this line
>   -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Temp to the idea.exe.vmoptions file (in C:\Program Files\ideaIU-11.1.4\bin)
>   And make sure the C:\Temp exists.

Source : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5941#u=1401303711495

Answer (score 0):

The `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` is occur when `underlying method` throws the exception. if method which has been `invoked`/call with `reflection API`, throwing an exception. and reflection API will wrap  exception in to `InvocationTargetException` which throw by underlying method. for more understanding you can refer below link of `stackover flow` Question Asked by : `user550413` and Answer by many java experts. i think you can get suitable answer on this link.

[What could cause java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6020719/7801800)

Comment: Thank, i came across what happend to me and it was non-ASCII characters in path.