# constructor.newInstance() throws java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException even though the constructor exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My current code looks something like this -

```
// Overridden constructors
public class InstRoMapping{

    public InstRoMapping(){}

    public InstRoMapping(Mappings mappings, ResourceMapping resourceMapping){
        this.resourceId = mappings.getResourceId();
        this.version = BigDecimal.valueOf(mappings.getVersion());
        // ... more code
    }
}
```

Somewhere in a different serviceimpl fn -

```
Constructor constructor = entityClass.getConstructor(mongoClass, iterableClass);
// debugger shows constructor is - InstRoMapping(Mappings,ResourceMapping)
for(T data : mongoData){
    List<Object> ob = (List<Object>) getMethod.invoke(data, null);
    for(Object o : ob){
        T flattenedObject = (T) constructor.newInstance(data, o);
        //debugger shows data is of type - Mappings and o is of type - ResourceMapping
    }
}
```

But it throws an exception inside the for loop while performing `constructor.newInstance(data, o)`

Exception -

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)  at com.citi.insight.resource.mongotooraclemigration.service.impl.MongoOracleServiceImpl.getMongoDataAsRequired(MongoOracleServiceImpl.java:61)  at com.citi.insight.resource.mongotooraclemigration.service.impl.MongoOracleServiceImpl.insertIntoOracleDb(MongoOracleServiceImpl.java:74)  at com.citi.insight.resource.mongotooraclemigration.MigrationController.migrateMongoToOracle(MigrationController.java:43)  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)  at com.citi.insight.userdetailscache.domain.impl.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:142)  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)  at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)  at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)  at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)  at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)  at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)  at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)  at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:68)  at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.instrument.web.TraceWebServletConfiguration$LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletConfiguration.java:131)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)  at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.tomcat.TraceValve.invoke(TraceValve.java:103)  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at com.citi.insight.resource.ora.model.InstRoMapping.<init>(InstRoMapping.java:339)  ... 99 common frames omitted
```

However, it works fine with other Class with a similar constructor -

```
public class InstRoCoversheet {
     public InstRoCoversheet(Coversheets coversheet, ResourceCoverSheet resourceCoverSheet){
        this.resourceId = coversheet.getResourceId();
        // ... more code here
     }
}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [What could cause java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020719/what-could-cause-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception). For your case -  `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at com.citi.insight.resource.ora.model.InstRoMapping.<init>(InstRoMapping.java:339)` - meaning that either `data` or `o` is null (most likely).

Comment: as commented above, the important part is at the very end of that EXTREMLY LONG error message (I wonder where the newline character ended) Now we just need to know which is the line `339` of `InstRoMapping.java`

Comment: @Chaosfire you are right. an attribute inside o was null. I was doing some op with it. and it was throwing npe. thanks!

Comment: Please format your stack trace properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments suggested, it was the problem at #339 in InstRoMapping.java It was throwing an NPE inside the overridden constructor.